# Reading and writing Tridion content

Tags: api, content-manager, 2013

What is the best way to read and write Tridion content programmaticaly? I want to build a migration tool that writes some pages and binary files to Tridion. I was thinking to try out the Content Delivery Web service API.

Comment: Migration tools are tough to do well.  I would suggest to do a manual migration and support it with scripts that do specific things or create reports for the authors.  Bart Koopman wrote a nice post here, http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-say-goodbye-to-your-migration-tool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Content Delivery Web Service is mainly for delivery of content that is already managed and/or published by Tridion.

To interact with the Content Manager programmaticaly, the recommended extension point is the Content Manager Core Service.

From the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)):

> The Core Service is a Web service that allows applications to interact
>   with the Content Manager. For example, Content Manager clients such as
>   Experience Manager and Content Manager Explorer interact with the
>   Content Manager through the Core Service, and you can use the Core
>   Service to integrate external systems with SDL Tridion. You also use
>   the Core Service to implement Automatic Activities to control
>   Workflow.
>
> The Core Service is a SOAP Web service based on Windows Communication
>   Foundation. It supports WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 and more advanced WS-*
>   protocols.